# Converting decimal to octal

Tags: c++, beginner, algorithm, number-systems

This is a simple program converting user input decimal numbers into octal ones.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
main()
{
    int de,oc,y,i=1,octal;
    float decimal,deci,x;
    cout<<"Enter decimal no :: ";
    cin>>decimal;
    de=decimal;
    deci=decimal-de;
    cout<<"("<<decimal<<")10 = (";
    while(de>0)
    {
        oc=de%8;
        de=de/8;
        octal=octal+(oc*i);
        i=i*10;
    }cout<<octal<<".";
    while(deci>0)
    {
        x=deci*8;
        y=x;
        deci=x-y;
        cout<<y;
    }
    cout<<")8";
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot it is a correct program i needed this program its very helpful to me

Answer (score 3):

Just, i don't understand why?

What's wrong with (for integer):

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    int input;
    std::cout << "Enter decimal number: ";
    std::cin >> std::dec >> input;
    std::cout << '\n' << std::oct << input << '\n';
}
```

And about your code:

- Avoid `using namespace std`, it's a bad practice
- Just `main()` isn't a valid prototype for the entry point, at least use `int main()
- Define variables in the closest scope possible.
- Try naming variable consistently
- `de=de/8;` can be simplified to `de /= 8;`
- floating point conversion is a bit more tricky than just doing what you do

**Edit**: After testing it (and correcting `main()` and) : **Your code just doesn't work, even for an integer value**

```
Enter decimal no :: (0)10 = (32767.)8
Enter decimal no :: (8)10 = (32776.)8
Enter decimal no :: (10)10 = (32779.)8
```

[Test yourself](https://wandbox.org/permlink/cdXqEQrfp8vDOWqd)

Comment: i have checked it on dev c++ its working 100%. and i have checked your method that was great but can you tell me how it will work for fraction.

Comment: if you want to check my program just copy it and paste in dev c++ than tell me if there is any bug.

Comment: which compiler do you use? which version? which flag? Allow me to doubt a bit

Comment: `using namespace std;` is only bad in header files, not regular code. In fact, using it is the whole point of having namespaces in the first place. Otherwise you could just rename everything in `std` namespace as `std_something` and remove namespaces from the language.

Comment: Do you know about namespaces? Theirs purposes? You Don't want to expose the whole `std` namespace to use it. And here, if he really want to use it, he just have to put `using namespace std;`inside the main, at the top. Here he dont have collision (He dodged `std::oct` and `std::dec`), but check out this [tread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: @Calak *sigh* Just because some thread calls something bad practice doesn't make it bad. If that were the case, every language with namespaces wouldn't have implemented the same bad practice. Opening namespaces is bad if you are using multiple of them or plan on ever using multiple of them. If all you are doing is using std, then there's nothing wrong with it.

Comment: here I still suspect that he had a name collision with `std::oct` and `std::dec` which he fixed by shortening his variable names. But hey, since you say it ... In my opinion, it is better to simply discourage this use to beginners by explaining why it is a bad habit not to take.

Comment: I don’t believe std::oct actually modifies the data, only the output. If the goal was to actually convert data, I believe you would have to do something like what he is doing.

Comment: No. Internally data is stored as an integer. Binary, octal, decimal, hexadecimal... Your processor just don't care, It's an integer. What's the OP modify is the representation of this integer (a string, const char* or whatever) as `std::oct` or `std::hex`  does. Not plus, not less.